# linking g++ and lib in the make file not working

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I'm compiling with g++, but when I run make, I get the following error:

```
    ./libnbmdt.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
    ./libnbmdt.so: undefined reference to `zlibVersion'
    ./libnbmdt.so: undefined reference to `inflate'
    ./libnbmdt.so: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
    ./libnbmdt.so: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [nbbid2md] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make: *** [nb/nbmdt] Error 1
```

Has anyone seen this before? I guess `-l<somelibrary>` is needed, but I don't know which one ... it's a c++ program by the way. I guess zlib is missing when g++ tries to link them?
some of the libraries being used are:

```
MT_VLIBS = \
libjansson.a \
libnbI18N.a \
libnbslidlC.a \
libnbslidlS.a \
libcurl.a \
libVdb \
libnborb \
libnbbase \
-lvxul \
-lvxssl \
-lvxcrypto
```

I can't share the makefile unfortunately.
Thanks

Comment: can you post the makefile, or how you build it?

Comment: Since you know zlib is missing, why not add it to your link line?

Comment: Yes, do you know which flag to use?
-lz
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem today by adding a $if condition on my makefile in other to use -lz flag.
It's sort of complicated, but I got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are right - the "-lz" flag is the one to be used. The ZLib is not linked thus not "inflate" functions.

Mind the following: "-lz" must be after "-lnb*" stuff, because the linking order is important with GCC toolchain.

Comment: I did add the -lz flag, but know I have the same errors I did before adding -lvxul \ -lvxssl \ -lvxcrypto

Comment: libcurl depends on zlib, where is the "-lz" flag added by you ? After libcurl ?

Comment: MT_VLIBS = \
libjansson.a \
libnbI18N.a \
libnbslidlC.a \
libnbslidlS.a \
libVdb \
libnborb \
libnbbase \
-lvxul \ -lvxssl \ -lvxcrypto \ -lcurl

Comment: Excuse me, I see no "-lz" - is that a problem in the comment editor here or you just forgot ?  Try  "MT_VLIBS = libjansson.a libnbI18N.a libnbslidlC.a libnbslidlS.a libVdb libnborb libnbbase -lvxul -lvxssl -lvxcrypto -lcurl -lz"

Comment: I have a file called libraries.mk that does not have -lcurl. So the error is UNIX LIBRARIES NOT DECLARED in libraries.mk: -lcurl

Comment: it's not Android NDK ... it's just a C++ makefile.

Comment: Sorry, confused by the .mk extension (too much of NDK for me). Can you dump the actual command for the "ld" tool ?